# How to repair a partition damaged by a power outage

Tags: mount, data-recovery, vmware, vmware-workstation, 23.10

I was worked with `VMWare` and my system suddenly power off.

After I power on my system my virtual machine partition doesn't mount and return this error!

[image: Mount Error]

How can i fix it and recovery my files?

I use command line but it's not help

```
sudo mount /dev/sda3 /media/Mohammad-Abbasi/DataAccess
```

> $MFTMirr does not match $MFT (record 3). Failed to mount '/dev/sda3':
> Input/output error NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware
> fault, or it's a SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run
> chkdsk /f on Windows then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the
> /f parameter is very important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID
> then first activate it and mount a different device under the
> /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g. /dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please
> see the 'dmraid' documentation for more details.

Comment: Is it a NTFS volume? Does it work in windows? Why is vmware relevant?

Comment: @vidarlo drive that `vmware` virtual machine file i saved in NFTS type partition and be saved in additional internal hard disk

Comment: The partition you're attempting to mount is NTFS? Or is it a vmware disk in EXT4 or similar stored on a NTFS partition?

Comment: @vidarlo I installed `vmware work station` in `ext4` partition but I was save virtual machine created in NFTS partition from another hard disk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer found

We just need repair partition with **Disks** program with select `Repair Filesystem` in `Additional partition option` like below image

---

**Up date**

**Note :** below image took after operation is worked correctly and mounted partition. for better see other users

[image]

Next every files recovery

**Note :** this operation recovery your file or remove all them but in my case work correctly and recovery my files